# Angular 4 - Conditional useHash when history not available (IE9)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to setup my app so that the routerModule useHash is false unless history isn't available in which case it sets it to true.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: !window['Modernizr'].history}) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

This works fine until I build for production at which point the conditional is changed to false. I have tried to run a function to set the value but it will not let me build the project like that. Is there anything I can do to get it to work?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @j2L4e I don't get an error with that code, when it's compiled it just converts !window['Modernizr'].history to !0 so it always uses hashes. If i then change it back in the bundle it works again so I need a way to inject that variable at run time or to stop it from converting it during build.